# Did this character drown in Tron Legacy?

Tags: tron-legacy

### Did Tron drown? Is a program capable of drowning?

We see Clu and Tron fighting over Light Jet baton and Clu steals it. After that, Tron is seen descending into what looks like water. Is there any information what looked to be water in the program world , that Tron fell to the depths and drowned in the substance?　Is there anything that explains what happened?

Comment: Legitimate, concise question. +1  Better to leave a comment explaining how the question might be improved before resorting to a downvote.

Comment: Programs do seem to interact with their environment in such a way that they do seem to "die" (especially from impacts - the arena fights, for example). "Drowning" is probably another such environmental interaction.

Comment: Thanks @Praxis , I was told this, http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9919/is-it-possible-to-ask-for-moderators-to-check-if-a-user-has-abnormally-downvoted#comment28424_9919

Comment: You have two different questions here: **1.** "Are programs capable of drowning?" and **2.** "Did Tron drown?". The latter can be closed following the [future-works policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/21267).

Comment: @Mooz, one and the same. Tron is a program, "did he drown?"

Comment: @Mooz - Closing due to future works is a big stretch when there's no other projects in this setting being developed.  Answers might be speculative, but the question is solid.  Might also be moot, since they shut off the system by the end, but we'll see what people come up with.

Comment: *Still groping for his master's hand, Rinzler continued falling to the sea below. . . .While Rinzler fell, Quorra struggled to keep from crashing. Using all her skills, she managed to skid the jet to a soft landing on a black beach.* - [Tron Legacy: Junior novelisation](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON:_Legacy_Junior_Novel).

Comment: in the original Tron, IIRC they find a liquid pure energy source and drink from it. Flynn seems to find it addictive, or just super refreshing. just thoight it worth mentioning, maybe not all grid liquids are the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**We don't know.**

Tron's ultimate fate isn't made clear in any of the film's associated media. We know from [Tron: Uprising](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON:_Uprising) that *brief* immersion into the [Sea of Simulation](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Sea_of_Simulation) isn't fatal and we see in [Tron: Betrayal](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON:_Betrayal) that ISOs are actually born in the sea, prior to its being poisoned by Clu.

That being said, there's every indication that the sea, especially in its poisoned state is deadly to basic programs since it was intended to act as a physical barrier to the portal.

**He probably drowned** although he did enjoy a moment of redemption just before he died.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: Impossible to say at the moment.

Out of universe, since Bruce Boxleitner (Alan Bradley / Tron's original actor) isn't getting any younger, chances are we won't see Tron in a live action movie anymore. But...

(Spoilers are from Uprising, towards the final episodes!)

As Valorum [mentioned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134018/769), what Tron fell into is (most likely) the Sea of Simulation, and having been poisoned, Tron's chances of survival are reduced - let alone the question whether programs can actually "swim". However, (especially if you've seen Uprising, you'll know) Tron is not an average program. He's been [ported](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/54910/769) from another system (the encom system he and Flynn liberated from the MPC) which might imply a certain adaptivity, and he was specifically programmed to be different from your average word processor or spreadsheet application. Clu's betrayal has not already turned him into Rinzler, but

> merely corrupted his program, which he and [Beck](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Beck) managed to cure at the finale of Uprising.

Since Uprising unfortunately got canceled, there is no way to tell how he became Rinzler, though

> the appearance of Clu's fleet at the finale hints at an epic battle etc. or maybe even a heroic self-sacrfice (which would fit Legacy's ending...).

The last thing we see in Legacy is his original "Illumination" turning *on*. My *interpretation* is that the remainder or "Rinzler" died, while Tron finally fully "awoke".

So, is there hope? Well, given the movies ending where Flynn merged with Clu, which seemed to cause a significant explosion, chances are the (literally) resurfacing Tron still got wiped with the entire area or even Grid.

Too pessimistic? Well, Sam did a mysterious download at the end, and fortunately there is ["Flynn lives"](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xhkp04_tron-the-next-day-flynn-lives-revealed-tr3n-teaser-1_shortfilms) - yes, that's ["The next day"](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/TRON:_The_Next_Day), a Teaser for the unfortunately [canned](http://variety.com/2015/film/news/tron-3-cancelled-disney-1201508421/) Tron 3. The implication of that slogan and teaser seems to be Kevin Flynn survived merging with Clu, and that in turn might include the Grid and Tron. Or Sam downloaded a snapshot before Clu messed everything up... [Maybe](https://www.change.org/p/walt-disney-revive-tron-3) we'll know some day, maybe not...